# Application of derivative - how to calculate change in error

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Problem: If the error committed in measuring the radius of the circle is $0.05\%$ then find the corresponding error in calculating the area.

Solution: Let the error be denoted by $\delta r = 0.05\%$, therefore the corresponding error in calculating the area is:

$A = \pi r^2 $

$\frac{\delta A}{\delta r} = 2\pi r$

$\Rightarrow \delta A = 2\pi r \delta r$

Please suggest if this is the right approach. If not, please help me solve this problem along with the concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.  When you see $\delta r = 0.05\%$ it really means that $r$ is measured within $0.05\%$, so the proper reading is $\frac {\delta r}r=0.05\%=5\cdot 10^{-4}$.  I don't know if this is in your text, but when errors are quoted as percents, they are relative, not absolute, errors.  Similarly, you are being asked for $\frac {\delta A}A$.  So divide your equation by $A=\pi r^2$ to get $\frac {\delta A}A=2\frac {\delta r}r$

Comment: If you try this out on other plane geometrical figures, you'll find that the same relative error relation holds: the "2" comes from the _dimension_ of the geometrical object. Taking this to solid figures, the relation is $\ \frac{\delta V}{V} = 3 \frac{\delta r}{r} \ $ . (This even applies to objects of _fractal_ dimension [with the appropriate extension of the meaning of "volume"].)